# Prevent custom serialization of specific field

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

Assume that I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    private Date dateToBeCustomeSerialized;
    private Date dateToBeDefaultSerialized;
}
```

In my Spring Boot application I need to serialize every `Date` object to a `String`. For that purpose and in order to avoid inserting `@JsonSerializer` everywhere, I have introduced a custom Serializer at application level.

The problem is that I want to avoid using the custom serializer on fields with name (not value) `dateToBeDefaultSerialized` and I cannot seem to find a way to do this.

This is how my custom "global" `Date` Serializer looks like:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper serializingObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new DateSerializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);

    return objectMapper;
}

public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(value);
        gen.writeString(date);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to serialize properties of name `dateToBeDefaultSerialized` using the default serializer?

Comment: In a Spring Boot application you could change the jackson date formatter using the property: `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd`

And then write your custom serializer to modify the behaviour on the "dateToBeDefaultSerialized" fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get the name of currently serialized field by implementing `ContextualSerializer`. The default serialization is available through `SerializerProvider`. Try rewriting the serializer like this:

```
class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> implements ContextualSerializer {
    private boolean doCustom;

    DateSerializer() {}

    private DateSerializer(boolean doCustom) { this.doCustom = doCustom; }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (doCustom) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            String date = sdf.format(value);
            gen.writeString(date);
        } else {
            provider.defaultSerializeDateValue(value, gen);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<Date> createContextual(SerializerProvider config, BeanProperty property) {
        boolean doCustom = property == null || !"dateToBeDefaultSerialized".equals(property.getName());
        return new DateSerializer(doCustom);
    }
}
```